# angular bootstrap modal service not working

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I created a common modal service in my application.
But it's not working somehow. Some small thing am missing on this plunker but am not able to figure out.

Based on passed parameter either it will open error-dialog or cancel-dialog.

Find [PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/VvlKYnblGIM22UwrniXT?p=preview) here

Here is 
**JS**

```
    // create angular app
var validationApp = angular.module('validationApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

// create angular controller
validationApp.controller('mainController', function($scope, ModalService) {

  var vm = this;
  // function to submit the form after all validation has occurred          
  vm.submitForm = function() {


    // check to make sure the form is completely valid
    if ($scope.userForm.$valid) {
      alert('our form is amazing');
    }

  };

  function openDialog() {
    alert('why am not showing');
    ModalService.openModal('Analysis Error', 'Complete Application Group configuration prior to running analysis.', 'Error');
  }

});
//controller fot dialog
validationApp.controller('ErrorDialogCtrl',
  function($uibModalInstance, message, title, callback) {
    alert('sfdsfds');
    var vm = this;
    vm.message = message;
    vm.onOk = onOk;
    vm.onContinue = onContinue;
    vm.onDiscard = onDiscard;
    vm.callback = callback;
    vm.title = title;

    function onOk() {
      $uibModalInstance.close();
    }

    function onContinue() {
      $uibModalInstance.close();
    }

    function onDiscard() {
      vm.callback();
      $uibModalInstance.close();
    }
  });
// common modal service
validationApp.service('ModalService',
  function($uibModal) {

    return {
      openModal: openModal
    };

    function openErrorModal(title, message, callback) {
      $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: 'ErrorDialog.html',
        controller: 'ErrorDialogCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        backdrop: 'static',
        size: 'md',
        resolve: {
          message: function() {
            return message;
          },
          title: function() {
            return title;
          },
          callback: function() {
            return callback;
          }
        }
      });
    }

    function openCancelModal(title, message, callback) {
      $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: 'CancelDialog.html',
        controller: 'ErrorDialogCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        backdrop: 'static',
        size: 'md',
        resolve: {
          message: function() {
            return message;
          },
          title: function() {
            return title;
          },
          callback: function() {
            return callback;
          }
        }
      });
    }

    function openModal(title, message, modalType, callback) {
      if (modalType === "Error") {
        openErrorModal(title, message, callback);
      } else {
        openCancelModal(title, message, callback);
      }
    }
  }
);
```

Opening Dialog in **HTML**

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="openCancelDialog()">Open Cancel Dialog</button>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="openErrorDialog()">Open Error Dialog</button>
 </div>
```

**Cancel Dialog HTML**

```
<div>
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">{{vm.title}}</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p ng-bind-html="vm.message"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="vm.onContinue()" id="continue">Continue</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="vm.onDiscard()" id="discard">Discard</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**ErrorDiaog HTML**

```
<div>
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">{{vm.title}}</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p ng-bind-html="vm.message"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="vm.onOk()">ok</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrong in your js file, you need to declare function like below. you just copy these code and put it in your file then it will work fine.

***NOTE:*** not **ModalService.showModal**, it should be **ModalService.openModal** 
[check your code here](https://plnkr.co/edit/DvHTz4T1ejj9YNhYae4I?p=preview)

```
$scope.openCancelDialog = function() {
alert('why am not showing CAncel');
ModalService.openModal('Analysis Error', 'I am Error Type', 'Error');

}


$scope.openErrorDialog = function() {
console.log('why am not showing Error');
ModalService.openModal('Analysis Error', 'I am cancel Type', 'Cancel');
}
```

Comment: not part of this question, but can you help me in unit testing the modal services and ErrorController?

Comment: Sure tell me , how can I help u

Comment: I am quite new to unit test, not sure how to start unit test for this ModalService and Errorcontroller. If you can show me the way by covering UT, I will catch up.

Comment: can you plz cover the UT at plunker. That would be great help. I am stuck.

Comment: Chrome is good for unit testing for angular js. Just press f12 from your keyboard and fix chrome as debug then you will properly test

Comment: For today I can't show you, bcoz I m little busy. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

i've created a new PLNKR here: 
https://plnkr.co/edit/3RBJneSt7RCClrJ5Hba2?p=preview

```
$scope.submitForm = function() {    
      //check to make sure the form is completely valid
       if ($scope.userForm.$valid) {
         alert('our form is amazing');
       }

}; 
$scope.openCancelDialog = function(){
   //alert('why am not showing CAncel');
   ModalService.openModal('Analysis Error', 'I am Error Type', 'Error');
 }


 $scope.openErrorDialog = function(){
    //alert('why am not showing Error');
    ModalService.openModal('Analysis Error', 'I am cancel Type', 'Cancel');
 }
```

Comment: actually those clicks were not getting triggered, that was the key thing. still Message binding is not working. help me if u able to figure out why message binding is not working.

Comment: both answers caught same mistake. I accepted who answered first. :)

Comment: I answered 1st 

Comment: I've updated the plnkr , now the clicks are trigggered and everything seems to working fine ;)